# abline in boxplot only on canvas

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I wanted to add an `abline()` to a boxplot, but it is drawn all over the graphic and not just in the canvas. Is there a workaround?

```
boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars, main = "Car Milage Data",
        xlab = "Number of Cylinders", ylab = "Miles Per Gallon") 
abline(v = 2.5, col = "grey", lty = 2)
```

[image: boxplot]

Comment: It works well for me. What do you mean with *"abline in the canvas"*?

Comment: Hi @DarrenTsai. I added a screenshot now. Could you take another look?

Comment: Try `par(xpd = F)` and run your code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Darren Tsai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10068985/darren-tsai) whose suggestion in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63373348/abline-in-boxplot-only-on-canvas/63374287#comment112061678_63373348):

> Try `par(xpd = F)` and run your code again.

fixed the problem.

Comment: Better use `xpd` in the `abline` call: `abline(v=2.5, col="grey", lty=2, xpd=FALSE)` which avoids manipulating the `par` options.